# Коды клавиш различных клавиатур

Tags: клавиатура, кроссплатформенность

Доброго времени суток.

Возможна ли ситуация, когда на разных машинах или системах нажатая клавиша ESC (или любая другая клавиша) будут иметь разный числовой код? Если, да - объясните пожалуйста при каких условиях возможна такая ситуация (или укажите источник, где можно подробно об этом почитать).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он никогда не меняется, он зарезервирован, зачем тогда таблица *ASCII*.

Comment: А если разные клавиатуры имеют разные модели и/или разную раскладку? Тоже не ничего не поменяется? Просто я читал, что разные клавиатуры могут иметь разные скан-коды одних и тех же клавиш.

Comment: Ответом же написали, все основные клавиши, зарезервированы своим числовым значением и об этих значениях ты можешь узнать в ASCII, и не имеет значения какая клавиватура

Comment: @Bakuard Вы в вопросе ни слова ни сказали о том, что имеете ввиду скан-коды. Да, теоретически они могут различаться, но тогда работа такой клавиатуры будет невозможна без отдельного драйвера и главное, вы даже с такой клавиатуры в настройки bios не зайдете, потому что bios то же нужен будет драйвер. Даже если какой то производитель клавиатуры на это пойдет и изменит скан-код Esc, то при нормальном драйвере вы об этом даже не узнаете, потому что ОС работает уже с ascii кодами, а драйвер отлично переведет сканы в ascii.

Comment: Спасибо, Mike. Ситуация прояснилась. С ваших слов я понял следующее - ascii это стандарт для всех привычных нам клавиатур и беспокоится тут не о чем. А если клавиатуры имеют разное кол-во клавиш? Допустим это какая-нибудь клавиатура для ввода текста на китайском или японском. В этом случае кол-во клавиш, их расположение, назначение может отличаться от привычных нам клавиатур. Что тогда в этом случае? Используется какое-то расширение для ascii или что-то другое?